# ksoap object property cannot cast

Tags: android, casting, ksoap

I am using ksoap library with the android studio IDE also successfully getting response of web service (I saw it from debuging). Normally this code was working; however, it gives me error this time any help about it, thank you.

```
   response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); // works I do got response
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){ // counting works, it is getting in to for loop
     Object property = response.getProperty(i); // error: cannot find local variable 'property',response working but it is not capble to cast it to property. 
     SoapObject swListSoap = (SoapObject) property;
     String SoapName = swListSoap.getProperty(TAG_NAME).toString();
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was parsing soap object to integer or double (Recommed, use string as it possible..).
For example if you want to parse soap object property by TAG_NAME ="NAME"; do not use:

```
int SoapLineName = Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty(TAG_LINENAME).toString());
```

Use:

```
String SoapLineName = (soapObject.getProperty(TAG_LINENAME).toString());
```

I had trouble both scanning property and parsing to listview. Solution use String..